# DRAM Self-Refresh not the Lowest Power Mode

Tags: power, computer-architecture, ddr3, energy-saving, dram

I have a `DDR3L Samsung DRAM` on my Laptop. Based on page 23 of its [datasheet](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/global.semi/file/resource/2017/11/DS_4GB_1.35V_DDR3_4Gb_E_die_UnbufferedSODIMM_Rev11.pdf), `IDD6` or the `Self-Refresh` current is much higher than `IDD2P0`, `IDD2P1` and `IDD3P`, which are the `Precharge/Active Power-Down` modes. Of course, `IDD5B` (i.e., the `Burst Refresh` current, which is responsible for refresh when `Self-Refresh` is not used) should be *scaled* based on the refresh period and *added* to the latter three values. But, even after that, it seems that the `Self-Refresh` power mode, is not the deepest power mode in this `DRAM` device. Am I missing something?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Is there an error state? Are you trying to improve power consumption? This is a very low level question and likely only helpful to electrical engineering

Comment: These currents are used for calculating `DRAM` power consumption. There are some power simulation tools such as `Micron Power-Calc`, `DRAMPower` and `Vampire` that use the currents as the input. The model used for `DDR3` for `Micron Power-Calc` can be found, here: https://www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/technical-note/dram/tn41_01ddr3_power.pdf. Reducing `DRAM` power consumption is an active area of research in computer engineering. @music2myear, Do you know the right place to ask this question?

Comment: Yes, and this site is for questions related to the basic functions of computers. There is an electrical engineering sister site that may be a more appropriate home for this question.